# MUI Autocomplete - Limit the number of selections

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

*Updated code to show the complete script logic.*

I am trying to limit the number of selections based on a number I get from the database, but for this example I have hardcoded it to 3. The error I am receiving is "Cannot read properties of undefined (selectedHeadcount)". The code works when I comment out *getOptionLabel* and *disableCloseOnSelect*.

```
  const rows = [
  { processPath: 'role1', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'role2', headcount: 3 },
  { processPath: 'role3', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'role4', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'role5', headcount: 1 },
];

type EmployeesDictionary = Record<string, Record<string, string[] | number>>;

export const CriticalRolesContent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const employeesList = ['john', 'sally', 'mark', 'kevin']
  console.log(employeesList, disableOptimizerButton);

  const newDictionary: EmployeesDictionary = {};

  rows.forEach((row) => {
    newDictionary[row.processPath] = {
      associates: [],
      selectedHeadcount: 0,
    };
  });

  console.log(newDictionary);

  const [associateList, setAssociateList] = useState<EmployeesDictionary>(newDictionary);

  const handleSelection = (processPath: string, associates: string[], reason: string, detail: any): void => {
    setAssociateList((prevAssociateList) => ({
      ...prevAssociateList,
      [processPath]: { associates: associates, selectedHeadcount: associates.length },
    }));
  };

  console.log(associateList);

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Process Path</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Associate Login</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Headcount Allowed</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
              <TableRow
                key={rowIndex}
                sx={{
                  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 },
                }}>
                <TableCell style={{ width: '35%' }}>{row.processPath}</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={{ width: '45%' }} component='th' scope='row'>
                  <Autocomplete
                    multiple
                    id='employee-list'
                    options={employeesList}
                    limitTags={3}
                    // getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
                    // getOptionDisabled={(option) => associateList.processPath.selectedHeadcount >= 3}
                    // disableCloseOnSelect={associateList.processPath.selectedHeadcount >= 3}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant='standard' label='Select Employees' />}
                    onChange={(event, list, reason, detail) => handleSelection(row.processPath, list, reason, detail)}
                  />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.headcount}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Specially want to know how rows is defined

Comment: Sorry I thought I added the rows object. I updated the code to include rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `associateList` value is something like this.

```
{
    "role1": {
        "associates": [],
        "selectedHeadcount": 0
    },
    "role2": {
        "associates": [],
        "selectedHeadcount": 0
    },
    "role3": {
        "associates": [],
        "selectedHeadcount": 0
    },
    "role4": {
        "associates": [],
        "selectedHeadcount": 0
    },
    "role5": {
        "associates": [],
        "selectedHeadcount": 0
    }
}
```

Its an object with keys of `rows.processPath`. Thats the reason `associateList.processPath.selectedHeadcount` is failing as there is no valued called `processPath` in it.

Other issues are:

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option} -> This should return string
options={row.name} -> This should be array
disableCloseOnSelect={associateList.processPath.selectedHeadcount >= 3} ->  This should a boolean value 
handleSelection(row.processPath, list, reason, detail) ->  Cant find declaration for this
```

You will have to change `associateList.processPath.selectedHeadcount` to `associateList[row.processPath].selectedHeadcount`. As `row.processPath` has the actual processPath that is available in the accociateList.

```
<Autocomplete
  multiple
  id="employee-list"
  options={employeesList}
  limitTags={3}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
  getOptionDisabled={() =>
    associateList[row.processPath].selectedHeadcount >= 3
  }
  disableCloseOnSelect={
    associateList[row.processPath].selectedHeadcount >= 3
  }
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="standard"
      label="Select Employees"
    />
  )}
  onChange={(event, list, reason, detail) =>
    handleSelection(row.processPath, list, reason, detail)
  }
/>
```

Edit: For the updated request you can declare a set to track which users are selected. Then based on user selection action you can keep updating it. Also you will have to update the handleSelection and getOptionDisabled prop.

```
// 1. Declare new state
const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState(new Set());

// 2. Updated handleSection

const handleSelection = (
  processPath: string,
  associates: string[],
  reason: string,
  detail: any
): void => {
  if (reason === "selectOption") {
    setSelectedUsers((prev) => {
      const newSet = new Set(prev);
      newSet.add(detail.option);
      return newSet;
    });
  } else if (reason === "removeOption") {
    setSelectedUsers((prev) => {
      const newSet = new Set(prev);
      newSet.delete(detail.option);
      return newSet;
    });
  }
  setAssociateList((prevAssociateList) => ({
    ...prevAssociateList,
    [processPath]: {
      associates: associates,
      selectedHeadcount: associates.length,
    },
  }));
};

// 3. Updated getOptionDisabled
// The selected option will be available in same row
getOptionDisabled={(option) => {
  const rule1 =
    associateList[row.processPath].selectedHeadcount >= 3;
  if (rule1) {
    return true;
  }
  if (
    associateList[row.processPath].associates?.includes(
      option
    )
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return selectedUsers.has(option);
}}
```

Comment: Hi, I made an edit to my code to show the entire logic, so you can reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for it @PandasM. I have updated the code for AutoComplete component.

Comment: Is it also possible to disable an employee selection if they have been selected already? The way I am considering of going about it is to useState on the employeeList then remove associates as they get added, or removed. Curious if you have another solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what you will have to do. Your state should be a Set to keep unique users. I have added code for that too. You can check it and replace it in your code.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the support.

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted in case it solves your question.

Comment: Question, in your example are the selections becoming disabled once the user has selected n users being greater than 3? Its still allowing me to choose, not sure if I'm missing something, or that logic was never added.

Comment: I missed the check. I have updated the answer in `getOptionDisabled`.

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea as to why I am receiving this error? Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectedHeadcount'). Perhaps due to the data being passed from Parent component to the Child component which is where this code resides in?

Comment: Can say exactly what is causing an issue without looking into the code. But such errors will occur when the object is probably null ie no value exists for associateList[<yourRole>]. If might either happen if you are trying to access the value before initialization or if you are resetting the values in some steps. @PandasM